# php validation e-mail on account creation

Tags: php, openshift, account, email-verification

I am having an issue in openshift:

I have this web app where you can create an account. After submitting the form, the app sends an email for e-mail for validation with the users e-mail and a hash code.

```
    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
        'from'    => 'tuhoramedica.cl <activaciondecuenta@tuhoramedica.cl>',
        'to'      => $nombre.' '.$apellido.'<'.$mail.'>',
        'subject' => 'Activación de cuenta',
        'text'    => '¡Gracias por suscribirte a tuhoramedica.cl!

Haz click en el link abajo para activar tu cuenta:
http://www.tuhoramedica.cl/phps/verifica.php?mail='.$mail.'&hash='.$hash.'

'
    ));
    header('Location: ../user_login_form.php');
```

The e-mail includes a link to a php file that activates the user account by modifying some of the users parameters set in db (verifica.php).

I get a file not found error.

I tried moving the file from the subfolder /phps/ to the main app folder and then get a server 500 error.

Any guesses on whats going on?

I am running the app on an openshift PaaS solution.

Regards.

Comment: Try change your header location to /path/to/user_login_form.php

Comment: if you go to that link through the browser does it work?

Comment: No, the link http://www.tuhoramedica.cl/phps/verifica.php?mail='.$mail.'&hash='.$hash is the problem.

Comment: Fixed it... thanks. It was a bit of code left over from an older file.